# Any Crud example for Meteor and react with SimpleSchema

Tags: meteor, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I make a simple page where data is inserted into database by a form using Refs of react.Can any body help me out how i can insert the data using aldeed:Simple schema or any curd example using that package.

please check my simple code for insertion.

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';

import {DoctorsList} from '../../../api/lists/DoctorsList.js';

export class DoctorCreate extends  Component
{
    addDoctor(event){
        event.preventDefault();
       var text= this.refs.DoctorName.value.trim();
        console.log(text);

            DoctorsList.insert({
                name:text,
                createdAt: new Date(),
                owner: Meteor.userId(),           // _id of logged in user
                username: Meteor.user().username,  // username of logged in user
            });
        this.refs.DoctorName.value="";

    }
    render()
    {
        return (
            <div className="container">


            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-sm-12">
                <form className="form" onSubmit={this.addDoctor.bind(this)}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label> Name</label>
                    <input ref="DoctorName" type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="name..."/>
                    </div>
                 <div className="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="save" className="btn btn-primary"/>
                </div>
                </form>
                </div>
                <br/>
                <a href="/doctors"  >Back to list </a>
                <hr/>
            </div>
            </div>


        )
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meteor official TODOs app is using simple schema. Link to github source https://github.com/meteor/todos/blob/1.3-module-exports/imports/api/lists/methods.js